# kivy listitem button with checkbox position

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to have a list item button with at the right a checkbox.
At the moment I have the checkbox in the center and the list item button text also in the center, so both widgets are mixed

How can I shift the checkbox at the right side ?

My class code :

```
class AttendanceListButton(FloatLayout, ListItemButton, CheckBox):
    root = FloatLayout()
    b1 = ListItemButton(pos_hint={'left': 1, 'center_y': .5}, size_hint=(None, None))
    b2 = CheckBox(pos_hint={'right': 1 , 'center_y': .5}, size_hint=(None, None))
    root.add_widget(b1)
    root.add_widget(b2)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what you're asking but I know that [ListView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.listview.html#) is now depreciated and replaced with [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html)